# How to pass argument these serial port into a function

Tags: c++, qt

```
int port = 1;
int CAS::open_config(void)
{
    int Ret = 0;
    serial.setBaudRate(QserialPort::Baud9600);
    serial.setDataBits(QserialPort::Data8);
    serial.setParity(QserialPort::NoParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QserialPort::OneStop);
    Ret = Configcom(Port,                );
}


int CAS::Configcom(unsigned char port,      )
{

}
```

> i need to pass argument those baudrate,parity, stopbits so that i can config those details in Configcom() function..

Comment: What's your problem ?

Comment: I have to use those serial.setbaudrate, setdatabits,setparity,stopbits in configcom() function how can I pass them ???

Answer (score 1):

your code suggest me, you dont need to do that, if you have somehow access to a **QserialPort** object named serial in the method `open_config` in the class **CSA**,

then you can have access to it in the method `CAS::Configcom`

but if somehow still want that then you can do something like

```
bool myMethod(QserialPort& s);
```

Comment: I want to write a condition for serialport that is for
close the serialport if already opened else open newly
please help
thank you